# Drupal show block data in a template region

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-templates

i have a dynamic block data (from database) for one of my modules and it is displayed in the right sidebar.

Now my template is changed and i want to integrate this block data into one of my .tpl files.
How can i proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the version of Drupal you are using, for Drupal 6 this would do it:

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', 'block_name');
print $block['content'];
```

For drupal 7, you could try this (clunkier) approach:

```
$block = block_load('views', 'block_name');      
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));        
print $output;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, i am using drupal6, but the snippet you gave did not work... i got solution from here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke/7#comment-14599

Comment: I was going to edit the answer to correct the D6 code version, but the example on that page is the same as the one I posted, the only difference I saw was in the block name parameter. Did I miss something? *I should update the D7 version though*.

Comment: Thanks, and finally this is what i used to make it work: **module_invoke('<my_module_name_that_has_block_code>', 'block', 'view', 0);** I suppose the first parameter must be the module name.

Answer (score 1):

In D6, if you want the block contents **themed** like a block:

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block', 'view', 'block_name');
print theme('block', (object) $block);
```